# Custom form not submitting on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that uses PrettyCheckable (http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) for checkbox/radio styling and Select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for dropdown styling.

I have a jsFiddle here with my markup: http://jsfiddle.net/pbuxc7xm/10/

The problem is that I'm trying to make the form submit on "change", meaning whenever someone either selects an item from the dropdown or selects one of the checkboxes.

```
$( "#countries" ).change(function() {
  $(this).parents("form").submit()
});

$( "#languages" ).change(function() {
  $(this).parents("form").submit()
});
```

The bottom line is that it's simply not working, for a reason unknown to me.

When I did an alert on change, it worked, but not to submit the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: if you change <button> to <submit> your code should work..but not sure why..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner there so such `<submit>` element in `HTML`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the form isn't submitting with jQuery's `.submit()` function.  But an easy work-around is to trigger the submit button's `click` event:

```
$('#submit').click();
```

This will submit the form normally.

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much. Assuming I have multiple forms on the same page, I just have to change the # ID right?

Comment: Yep.  You never want two elements on the page to have the same ID.